# Any small idea to decode this algorithm from PHP script

Tags: cryptography, encryption, cryptanalysis

So I think the algorithm is based on the php function `ENCODING_decode` defined in *includes/encoding.php* (which i don't have)   .
 The encoded result  `$xId_campaign_encoded` from the php script has always 24 alphanumeric characters

Comment: Ehrm this doesnt even look crypted

Comment: coded? . http://stackoverflow.com/users/118068/marc-b said it is crypted It's ASCII? Seriously... we're not cryptographers. . – Marc B 19 hours ago

Comment: The last edit to this post (revision 6) removed information crucial to the post, so it no longer makes sense.

Answer (score 5):

The user and campaign IDs seem to be hexadecimal numbers (of 32 and 48 bits respectively).  I see no obvious structure in them — they're definitely not printable ASCII byte strings.

The 24-char "result" strings are not hexadecimal, but they might be [base 36](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_36). However, if so, they're too long to be reliably decoded by PHP's [base_convert()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php) function.

However, if you look carefully at the sample strings, you'll notice that letters only appear in odd-numbered character positions.  This suggests that the strings might be encoded two characters at a time.  In fact, if you split each string into two-character pairs, *swap the letters in each pair* and decode them as base 36 numbers, all the values turn out to be less than 256.  Specifically, the strings you gave decode to the following hexadecimal strings:

```
z264643413z2e4l5i5744413 -> 6b 96 96 93 6d 6b 9e c9 c6 97 94 6d 
x2v2d4a4a4z2d464j5c464u2 -> 69 67 9d 9a 9a 6b 9d 96 c7 9c 96 66 
z2q274k523647454b4948464 -> 6b 62 97 c8 6e 96 97 95 9b 99 98 96 
13s2j55433x2m5n594u244a4 -> 6d 64 c7 95 6f 69 ca cb 99 66 94 9a 
74t2c4h5w20364j56474t254 -> 97 65 9c c5 68 6c 96 c7 96 97 65 95
```

These still show quite a bit of redundancy; for example, the upper nibble of each byte is always `6`, `9` or `c` = 12, and the lower nibbles aren't exactly uniformly distributed either:

```
0 =  0:  0 
1 =  1:  0 
2 =  2:  1 #
3 =  3:  1 #
4 =  4:  3 ###
5 =  5:  6 ######
6 =  6: 11 ###########
7 =  7:  9 #########
8 =  8:  3 ###
9 =  9:  5 #####
a = 10:  4 ####
b = 11:  6 ######
c = 12:  3 ###
d = 13:  5 #####
e = 14:  2 ##
f = 15:  1 #
```

In fact, plotting the frequency of all bytes as a table, with the upper byte as the row (showing only rows `6`, `9` and `c` for brevity) and the lower as the column, gives a curious picture:

```
  | 0123456789abcdef
--+-----------------
6 | 0010122112041311
9 | 0001238512312210
c | 0000011311110000
```

However, I can't immediately think of what might be generating such a byte distribution, but it does seem too distinct to be just a coincidence.

Comment: anyone can find the final solution for 10 usd?

Comment: A [rep bounty](http://security.stackexchange.com/privileges/set-bounties) might work better, although you'd need to acquire some more rep yourself before you can award one.